# Spring Integration Header value router with condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the header value router for the http status code on the reply channel. I want to redirect to the original payload to `afterSuccessChannel` if the status code is `200` else if any other status is in the header I want to send the payload to `afterFailuerChannel`. I am not sure if it is possible with `header-value-router` since there is no expression field. Is it possible with `header-value-router` or I have to use generic router for that purpose?

```
<int:header-value-router header-name="#{T(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders).STATUS_CODE}" input-channel="ccChannel" default-output-channel="ccLogger">
        <int:mapping value="200" channel="afterSuccessChannel"/>
</int:header-value-router>
```

Also I get the following error when using above router even though I get `http_statusCode=200` on header of the message:

```
ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'OK'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'OK' in the BeanFactory.; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'OK' is defined, headers={timestamp=1419419964606, id=eea83b65-0e72-bcda-d8fe-6d9bb4619fb4, history=errorChannel}]
```

I don't know why it is looking for OK channel.

Answer (score 3):

The header is an `HttpStatus` object (enumeration), not a simple String.

You need to map on the enumeration (in this case `OK`)

```
<int:mapping value="OK" channel="afterSuccessChannel"/>
```

**EDIT:**

In order to discard non-matches, you have to set `resolution-required="false"`.

Either of these works...

```
<int:header-value-router input-channel="foo" default-output-channel="baz" 
    resolution-required="false"
    header-name="#{T(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders).STATUS_CODE}">
  <int:mapping value="OK" channel="bar" />
</int:header-value-router>


<int:router input-channel="foo" default-output-channel="baz"
    resolution-required="false"
    expression="headers['#{T(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders).STATUS_CODE}'].toString()">
  <int:mapping value="200" channel="bar" />
</int:router>
```

Note that the second one is a regular router that uses a runtime expression to extract the numeric value of the header.

Comment: Great. I have one question though. Will this router be conditional? Conditional in the sense, if the value is not `OK`, will it route to `default-output-channel`?

Comment: Actually, I have a condition to route to `afterSuccessChannel` is status value is `200/OK` else route to `ccLogger`.